# Different button size - Bootstrap

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to create button group (text and icon buttons next to each other) with bootstrap 2.

```
<div class="btn-group chips">
  <button type="button"class="btn btn-large btn-success userChips">asdasd</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-large btn-danger removeUser">
       <i class="icon-minus-sign"></i>
  </button>
</div>
```

the size of the left button (the one with the icon) is smaller then the one with the text (the right one).

How do I fix this?

Comment: set a fixed with for both in css

Comment: Smaller in width ? both are large as you have set the class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give your buttons the same exact width.

```
.btn-large {width: 80px;}
```

Answer (score 1):

Apply a fixed width

```
.btn {
    width: 80px;
}
```

While applying a fixed with will get you the expectation, it carries with it a cost. Your buttons now can only have so many characters in them before they start falling behind.

```
.fixed .btn {
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    white-space: no-wrap;
}
```

Here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/itanex/5dxpc/) for you to check out.